# Input type number arrows bug with mozilla

Tags: html, css, input, mozilla

[image: input]

I removed the regular input arrows with the following code:

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

It works in all the browsers but the newest mozilla firefox. Am I doing something wrong or why the arrows wont dissapear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nevermind I already figured it out..

Here is the solution:

```css
input[type=number] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}
```